# Console Application Terminal UI with separate "windows"

Tags: java, terminal, console-application, java-console

I'm building java based console application where I need two windows of it. First window is for output and the second one will be used for entering commands for stopping application, restarting or something like it, nothing too big, just a simple textbox and window.

Any recommendations for console UI like it based in Java? Looking for best practices so I would be grateful. Thanks!